# Thread safe way to copy a HashMap

Tags: java

I have a scenario where I want to copy a HashMap into a new HashMap but in a thread safe manner. I want to do this to avoid any Concurrent Modification exceptions while copying the map.

Comment: You'll have to avoid writing to the map while copying it, probably by synchronizing.

Comment: Unless you have access to and can modify every place in the code that _writes_ to the map you're out of luck.  Or, substitute a `ConcurrentHashMap` at instantiation.

Comment: If you can't control access and type of the map, a hacky workaround is to catch CME and retry a couple of times in the hope of getting lucky. The success rate will obviously depend on how often the map is written to.

Comment: Will toArray method work as expected if I am interested in only the keySet of the Map https://www.journaldev.com/378/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception#to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-in-multi-threaded-environment . I think it should not but not sure

Comment: Are you actually using the `HashMap` across multiple threads? Have you actually run into a `ConcurrentModificationException`, or are you simply worried you might see one? What have you tried so far?

Comment: We are getting ConcurrentModificationException. See the options that I see are have a ConcurrentHashMap, keep a separate copy of HashMap, or synchronize all part. Though not saying they are not possible I wanted to know if there is an easy way.

Comment: As I said in my answer `ConcurrentModificationException` can happen even if you're not using multiple threads. If you *are* using multiple threads you can't safely use `HashMap` without synchronizing everything. The "easy" option would be to use `ConcurrentHashMap`, but it's difficult to give concrete advice without concrete example code to look at.

Comment: @dimo414 `ConcurrentHashMap` only makes each method call into the map thread safe. It does not make higher-level operations like copying out all elements thread safe. (`ConcurrentHashMap` has a `putAll` method that can copy another collection _into_ the map, but it doesn't have a method to copy all elements out.)

Comment: @TedHopp copying the contents of a `ConcurrentHashMap` is indeed thread-safe (as is any any other operation involving iterating over the map). It isn't _atomic_, but it is safe.

Comment: @dimo414 - Sure, it's thread safe in the sense of preserving the integrity of the data structure. But copying is only thread-safe if you're copying _from_ a `ConcurrentHashMap`. The problem here is copying from any old `HashMap`. I don't see how copying _into_ a `ConcurrentHashMap` helps with this problem. And wrapping the source `HashMap` in a `ConcurrentHashMap` won't help if there are other references to the map floating around in unsynchronized threads.

Comment: Consider posting a new question with more details about what you're trying to understand; I'd be happy to say more but it's difficult to do so in the comments of an old question. But it's perfectly safe to copy the contents of a HashMap into a CHM.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to ensure that the original HashMap is not modified while creating the new map. The most direct way to do this is to synchronize on the original map:

```
HashMap<K, V> original = ...

HashMap<K, V> copy;
synchronized (original) {
    copy = new HashMap<>(original);
}
```

This will only work in a thread-safe manner if all code that might modify `original` is synchronized on the same object (`original` itself, in my sample code, although it could be any shared object). If `original` is an object returned by `Collections.synchronizedMap()`, then you *must* synchronize on `original` for all synchronization to work properly; using another lock object won't work due to how synchronized maps operate internally.

Comment: Just to write that this is also not a thread-safe example.
Example is only doing sync on copy, but other code that modifies map can be without sync...

Comment: @BoskoPopovic - Did you read my entire answer? I specifically noted that code on every thread needs to respect the synchronization. I challenge you to provide any thread-safe solution at all if code on at least one thread ignores thread safety.

Comment: sorry, you are right. you wrote that all parts that modify the table need to be synced.

Answer (score 2):

First off, it's *never* safe to use a `HashMap` across multiple threads without some sort of external synchronization. If you're doing so currently and aren't running into issues that's just luck, and you'll see very strange bugs or even crashes in the near future.

The easiest option is to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`, which is designed to be safely used by multiple threads at the same time. You can then safely copy the map into another map whenever you'd like.

As Ted Hopp mentions, using `synchronized` blocks is a potential alternative, but it's much more error-prone if not done correctly.

---

Note also that you can get a `ConcurrentModificationException` even if you're not working with a `HashMap` across multiple threads. For example:

```
for (K key : map.keySet()) {
  map.remove(key);
}
```

would cause a `ConcurrentModificationException` because the map is modified "concurrently" with an attempt to iterate over its contents. So just seeing a CME does not mean that you need a thread-safe solution, you may simply need to change how you're modifying the collection:

```
Set<K> keysSnapshot = new HashSet<>(map.keySet());
for (K key : keysSnapshot) {
  map.remove(key);
}
```

Comment: Is map.keySet() thread safe because I think it also uses an iterator.

Comment: Will not copying to a new HashMap will cause KeySet Iterator to actually run and cause ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: No, `HashMap.keySet()` is not thread-safe, neither is any other part of `HashMap`. If you want to use a map across multiple threads you need to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` or explicit synchronization.

Comment: You won't get a `ConcurrentModificationException` if a) you're only using the map in one thread and b) you don't modify the map at the same time that you're iterating it. That's why the second example (first copying the keys into a set) is safe *for single-threaded usages of `HashMap`*.

Comment: How would you implement a thread-safe copy operation using `ConcurrentHashMap` without using some higher-level synchronization?

Comment: What's your concern exactly? You can safely access the contents of a `ConcurrentHashMap` even while it's being mutated by other threads. You _can't_ ensure that nothing else modifies the map at the same time, but that's generally a feature. If you want to prevent any mutations to the map you should indeed synchronize at a higher level, but if you do that then a standard `HashMap` will work just fine.

Comment: @dimo414 - I guess it depends on what one means by "thread-safe copy operation." I'm imagining a method that returns a copy containing exactly the contents of the map at the time the method is invoked, even in the presence of multi-threaded access to the map. In other words, I usually think of a "thread-safe operation" as pretty much synonymous with "atomic operation".

Comment: I mean, there's reason we have the separate terms "atomic" and "thread-safe", right? In a multi-threaded program it's not even necessarily meaningful to describe exactly what a concurrently-accessed data structure contains at a given time. Typically usages of concurrent data structures are implemented such that individual mutations don't violate the application's correctness or assumptions. Obviously sometimes atomic operations over the whole map is required, and in such cases CHM isn't what you'd use.

Answer (score -1):

Using

```
  var in = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
```

this will copy the map inside the mutex:

```
  private static <K, V> Map<K, V> copy(Map<K, V> in) {
    if (in == null) {
      return null;
    }
    Map<K, V> out = new HashMap<>();
    in.forEach((k, v) -> out.put(k, v));
    return out;
  }
```